# implementation of mounting external hdd and usb stick

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, gnome, automounting

Lately I've been interested in knowing how Ubuntu(bionic) and Fedora(27) implement the auto mount features and especially how to change the mount properties (noatime, relatime and other niceties.)

Various stuff I've found and want verification for:

- According to Google and various blogs that udisk2 has the mount properties hardcoded in the source files.
- Udisk2.service doesn't exist on my installations, which means that using `systemctl mask udisk2.service` will actually create a new symlink from PATH/udisk2.service -> /dev/null. (Which seems fine as we just turn everything into null)
- systemd.automount seems not to be configurable for mount options, and examples seems far away.
- Lastly we have `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false` (which ofcourse can have more parameters and gnome could be substituted for mate.

Anybody who successfully configured automount to have configurable mount options?

Lastly I would say that, this could look like a duplicate of previous posts, but I would like to see this as a collections of experiences in doing some basic stuff, which is not that transparent.

Comment: I am using `usbmount`, which has configurable mount options, but then I'm not using the Gnome desktop, have disabled `udisk2`, and not using systemd, so this may not be an option for you... and yes, I found all these system pretty intransparent.

Comment: It's rather ironic that having open source systems "they" make the systems more opaque, unless you go all custom, which you apparently have done. It might be the way to go. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Well, it's "for the desktop". Apparently that implies "the user is stupid, and we the programmers don't need to document anything". Of course one can read the source, document stuff for them, and add configurable options ...